# How to disable "tips" with Aura?

Tags: transactions, aura, tips

How can transaction tips be disabled or configured (say, limited) with Aura consensus?

[image: Substrate UI]

Answer (score 1):

Tips are just to provide priority to a transaction and you can find the logic of tip in `pallet_transaction_payment` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/HEAD/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs#L708), the function `get_priority` is where tip is being included in the transaction, you can configure it there.  Explain a little more what exactly you are trying to achieve so that i can answer appropriately.